# Why UITableView works but UIView doesn't

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to pop an view with textInput box and button. I can't understand why UITableView works but UIView doesn't.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.containerView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100,200,200)];
    [[self view]addSubview:self.containerView];
}
```

Use above code I can saw the view. But if I change to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100,200,200)];
    [[self view]addSubview:self.containerView];
}
```

I will get nothing, a black screen. Nothing displayed.
Could someone tell me the reason? Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, above code sit in My ViewController.m

Comment: What is the object type of `self.containerView` ?

Comment: Exactely check the defined type of `self.containerView`, if its `UITableView` just change it to`UIView`.

Comment: if you set a background color to containerView do you see something?

Comment: what colour are you expecting your containerView to be? Can you add the code from the header file as well to show where the containerView is initially declared

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much guys. It is the colour problem. The default colour is black, That's why I see nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100,200,200)];
self.containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

try this code
.